# Samsung s3 EditText.setText() hangs UI

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I have a number of different transitions happening in my application and everything works great. The only problem is that in one of the animations I have to use the `setText()` of editText and this blocks the UI for atleast 200ms on Samsung S3. Has anyone else faced this issue and is there any workaround it?

Comment: Use Traceview to determine exactly where your block is coming from.

Comment: I am sure it has something to do with a buggy setText(). I read up the documentation and saw that setText() method uses BufferType.EDITABLE. I tried using other buffer types but no use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with a hacky solution for it. Using the following method stops the lag.

```
editText.getText().clear()
```

If you want to write new text then

`editText.getText().clear(); 
editText.getText().append('blabla');`